# How to set group for new files that I gunzip?

Tags: permissions, gunzip

I am user myuser with primary group myuser. I get ftp'd a stack of files every so often and I want to gunzip them. The newly created unzipped files belong to myuser:myuser.

I want the newly created files to belong to myuser:othergroup; but I don't want to change my primary group affiliation, because I don't know if and how that will affect other scripts I have set up.

So the question is:

When I get a stack of files I use

```
gunzip *.gz
```

on them. How do I get the files created by this process to belong to a group other than my primary group?

Comment: You might be able to use a pipe character to direct the created files to another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you could use tool such as  [`sg`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sg) to run as different primary group (so new files created would inherit the primary group), but since [gunzip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gunzip) preserves ownership the likely the easiest way is changing the group of the files using [`chgrp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp) before running `gunzip`:

```
chgrp GROUP *.gz
```